Math concerns about NL $1°$ order DE in classical mechanics (drag force, low velocity) - integral of $1/x$
In this Classical Mechanics course, professor derives the speed of an object falling to the ground, taking into account the low-speed resistive force of the air on it.
At one point we have to integrate from speed $v_0 = 0$ to $v(t)$ an expression that I will simplify (by considering $\frac{mg}{\alpha} =1$). Here's the expression:
$$\frac{dv}{v-1} \tag{1}$$

Let me adopt for a moment a bit of mathematical formality.
Expression $(1)$ is the same as $$\frac{1}{x} dx$$
where $x=v-1$ and also note that the integration is now from $-1$ to $v(t)-1$.

I am wondering why we don't really bother about $v>1$ (i.e. $x>0$). I am noticing that, while considering $x>1$ is nonsense (it would yield a negative time when integrating $dt$, since the area from $-1$ to, say, $2$ would be positive), it could be worth considering the case $0<x<1$.
But I also note that integrating the inverse function from $-1$ to $0.5$ is strictly the same as integrating it from $-1$ to $-0.5$. So there's a kind of "mirror effect". My question then, is how do we translate in the physics realm this "anomality" in math ?

How comes the doubt about v>1 you integrate from v=0 to v(t) so v>1 is not excluded,neither if you integrate x from -1 to (v(t)-1)

Your question is exploring a mathematical relation that is physically impossible.
It will take infinite time for the initially $v_0=0$ to accelerate until it reaches $v=1$, and so there is no possibility for $v>1$, i.e. your $x>0$.
Note also that in your graph, $x=0$ is a mathematical singularity, which you cannot cross.
The professor is thus trying to avoid having to discuss impossibilities.

Even the professor's presentation is slightly ugly. You should take the negative of everything, so that the integral make up the logarithm is positive. You want to do this because then everything is not only physically pleasing, but also mathematically so.
There is really only one unique answer, as guaranteed by Picard–Lindelöf theorem
